# git-lfs asks for password twice for file?

Tags: git

I am running git 2.92 with latest git-lfs on some "login server" that has an older Redhat installation ( 2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 19 12:09:25 EST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux )

We recently moved our repositories from SVN to GIT, and that includes a lot of files which are now in a binary repository.

When I do a checkout on my local Ubuntu, and setup git-lfs; everything works nicely.

But when I run the same procedure on that remote server, the actual checkout will ask me twice for my password - for each file that git-lfs is responsible for.

I added

```
git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
```

to the repository config; but no change.

Any idea, anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution, but a workaround - a python script that simply loops and "expects" requests for passwords ... and provides them; until EOF.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pexpect
import sys

def main():
  command = input("Enter the command to invoke: ")
  password = input("Enter the password to send: ")

  child = pexpect.spawn(command)
  counter = 0

  while True:
    try:
        expectAndSendPassword(child, password)
        counter = logAndIncreaseCounter(counter)
    except pexpect.EOF:
        print("Received EOF - exiting now!")
        sys.exit(0)

def expectAndSendPassword(child, password):
  child.expect("Password .*")
  child.sendline(password)

def logAndIncreaseCounter(counter):
  print("Sent password ... count: {}".format(counter))
  return counter + 1

main()
```

If anybody finds that helpful, feel free to upvote ;-)